# How Should I be joining these tables?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have a SQL statement that joins 5 tables but I think I must be joining them incorrectly.  I have an asp.net form that allows input via check boxes and drop down lists so I'm building the SQL inside code based on the UI.

The criteria for the search will include fields from 3 different tables. The error I'm getting is

> *The multi-part identifier "openingReq.bgChk" could not be bound.*

I feel like my joins must be the issue, but I'm not sure how I should change them to make this work.

Here's the SQL statement

```
  SELECT COMPANY.NAME, 
       SITE.NAME, 
       OPENING.JOBTITLE, 
       ( OPENINGSCHED.WEEKLYHOURSLOW + '-' 
         + OPENINGSCHED.WEEKLYHOURSHIGH )                   AS weeklyHours, 
       ( OPENINGCOMP.WAGELOW & '-' & OPENINGCOMP.WAGEHIGH ) AS payRange 
FROM   COMPANY 
       INNER JOIN [SITE] 
               ON COMPANY.ORGID = SITE.ORGID 
       INNER JOIN OPENING 
               ON SITE.SITEID = OPENING.SITEID 
       INNER JOIN OPENINGSCHED 
               ON OPENING.OPENINGID = OPENINGSCHED.OPENINGID 
       INNER JOIN OPENINGCOMP 
               ON OPENINGSCHED.OPENINGID = OPENINGCOMP.OPENINGID 
WHERE  OPENING.JOBORWE = 'Job' 
       AND OPENING.OCCUPATIONCODE = 59 
       AND COMPANY.SECTORCODE = 202 
       AND OPENING.ONBUSROUTE = 1 
       AND ( OPENING.LANGCODE = 1 
              OR OPENING.LANGCODE = 7 
              OR OPENING.LANGCODE = 22 ) 
       AND OPENING.TIER = 1 
       AND OPENINGREQ.BGCHK = 1 
       AND OPENINGREQ.MINEXP = 'no minimum experience' 
       AND OPENINGREQ.MINED = 'no minimum education'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking through your query and I can't find a join to the `OPENINGREQ` table.
That would explain why SQL can't bind it!

Comment: Thanks!  I think I just got snow blind and needed another set of eyes.  That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a table or alias called "openingReq" in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the table `openingReq` in the JOIN anywhere - but the WHERE clause...

Answer (score 0):

`OPENINGREQ` doesnt exist on your context. Replace it with the correct table name or alias:

```
   AND OPENINGREQ.BGCHK = 1 
   AND OPENINGREQ.MINEXP = 'no minimum experience' 
   AND OPENINGREQ.MINED = 'no minimum education'
```